# Refer to a web page inside a jar file

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, jar, jersey

I have a working project. It includes another project which deals with REST as a rest-api.jar.

Now I have done an one-page UI for this REST API on AngularJS and provided it for the main app.

The problem is that I cannot find a way to refer to this page from the main project because this page MUST be within the rest_api.jar

This is a way I solved it. Simply redirecting to a page:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public void doGetAsHtml(@Context
UriInfo info, @Context
HttpServletResponse servletResponse) throws IOException
{
    servletResponse.sendRedirect("/web/pages/index.html");
}
```

So, is it possible to refer to a web page that is inside one of your project jar files and how this can be achieved?

Every answer is highly appreciated and responded immidiately.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what you mean by 'refer to'.

You can open a file that is on your classpath (e.g. in a jar file used by your application) using `Class.getResourceAsStream()` and passing it the path e.g. '/resource/html/index.html' (don't leave out the leading slash, and use slash not backslash).

Having opened that `InputStream` (perhaps wrapping it in a `Reader`) you can copy from there to the `OutputStream` of the `HttpServletResponse` (or a `Writer` wrapped around this `OutputStream`).

The reason you might want to open as a `Reader` and write as `Writer` is if the encoding of the file (in the jar) is not the encoding you want the HTML sent out as (e.g. as set in the response header).

(This is a generic approach, of course, and has nothing to do with REST or AngularJS.)

Comment: I tried this approach earlier, but I could not get an classpath value to correctly search the file.

Comment: Are you sure your file has been included in one of the .jar files that are deployed as part of your application?  (You can use `jar -tvf myfile.jar` to list the files in a .jar.)  And are you sure you have the right path to it?  If you don't `getResourceAsStream()` just returns null (i.e. you don't get an `IOException`).