# Path not found for a property file in Web application?

Tags: java, properties, fileinputstream

My Property file location is `WebRoot/WEB-INF/Test/property files/Question.properties`

Now I want to load the property file using FileInputStream. So I wrote the below code.

```
Properties pr = new Properties();
pr.load(new FileInputStream("WebRoot/WEB-INF/Test/property files/Question.properties"));
```

By the above code I got `java.io.FileNotFoundException`.I am using myeclipse for my development. Can any one suggest the path to read my properties.

Comment: Try this: in stead of directly opening an inputstream, put that path in a File object and print the value of getAbsolutePath(). What do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are opening it relative to the current directory.  Do you know what the current directory is?  Try creating a:

```
File f = new File("WebRoot/WEB-INF/Test/property files/Question.properties");
```

Then printing or debug the absolute path of the `File` object.  This will tell you what file you are actually trying to open (i.e. full path).

However, if you are trying to open a 'resource' bundled with your web app (as suggested by /WEB-INF/ being in the path) this is probably not a good way to do it.  One alternative is to build your 'resource' into one of your application's .jar files.

See here, for a related answer:
[Refer to a web page inside a jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22333647/refer-to-a-web-page-inside-a-jar-file/22333888#22333888)

Answer (score 0):

use  the method InputStream java.lang.Class.getResourceAsStream(String name) instead, this will work when you run your class within eclipse and outside eclipse. and use the same path as what you have mentioned in your code and append "/" at the front.
Hope this helps !

Comment: That won't help to get a resource from WEB-INF/Test though; that directory is not on the standard webapp classpath. It would work if the file was in WEB-INF/classes/Test.

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing right click on Question.properties file click on the properties get the Location of the file.

```
 Properties pr = new Properties();
 pr.load(new FileInputStream("Location of the file"));
```